# Recover overwritten file with eclipse git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, overwrite

I've overwritten one of my local changes in Eclipse to one of the files by mistake! How can I get my local changes back? I'm using Git in Eclipse and in the Team Synchronize window I clicked Overwrite to one of the files I did not want to!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use local history information from eclipse

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Right-click the file in a navigation view (e.g. the Project Explorer) and select Team > Show Local History.